# No keyword with name 'Get Child WebElement' found In Robot

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I want to get all child elements from Current page, for that I am using below code

```
${childElements} =  Get Child WebElement    xpath=//*
```

The above code throws an error No keyword with name 'Get Child WebElement'

Is there any other library for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

As you have figured out that these keywords are not yet in the published SeleniumLibrary versions.

In the event that you are processing an element or simply have a string locator then you can use the proposed code in SelenniumLibrary Pull Request [#702](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/pull/702) mentioned in the answer from @yash in a custom SeleniumLibrary extension.

In the below example there are two custom Robot Framework keywords to give you the keywords using the approach mentioned in #702:

1. Get Child Webelements
2. Get Parent Webelement

In the below example it shows that you can look for the parent and child using a regular locator `id=main` or a WebElement `${children[0]}`. This is handled by the python method `find_element(s)` of the `WebElement` python object.

Note: changed the keyword from `Evaluate` to `Call Method` for security reasons and readability.

**example.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary      

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Get Children Then Parent
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com    headlesschrome

    ${children}  Get Child Webelements   id=main
    ${parent}    Get Parent Webelement   ${children[0]}

    ${id}        Get Element Attribute   ${parent}    id
    Should Be Equal    ${id}    main

*** Keywords ***
Get Child Webelements
    [Arguments]    ${locator}

    ${element}    Get WebElement    ${locator}    
    ${children}     Call Method       
    ...                ${element}    
    ...                find_elements   
    ...                  by=xpath    value=child::*    

    [Return]      ${children}

Get Parent Webelement
    [Arguments]    ${locator}

    ${element}    Get WebElement    ${locator}      
    ${parent}     Call Method       
    ...                ${element}    
    ...                find_element    
    ...                  by=xpath    value=parent::*

    [Return]    ${parent}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This partially meets my expectation. I would want to iterate through end of the child element.

For ex
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr><th>Head 1</th><th>Head 2</th><th>Head 3</th></tr>
 </thead>
 
 <tbody >
  <tr><td>Row 1 Text 1</td><td>Text 2</td><td>Text 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2 Text 1</td><td>Text 2</td><td>Text 3</td></tr>
 </tbody>

</table>

I would like to get
0=> <th>Head 1</th>
1=> <th>Head 2</th>
n=> <td>Text 3</td>

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Those are not direct children of the parent `<table..>` and thus will not be returned by these keywords. If you want to return a list with those records then use `Get Webelements    //table[@id='SomeId']//tr/td|//tr/th`

Comment: I would want to get all child from div. for example
 <div>
  <span>Div Span 1</span><br>
  <span>Div Span 2<span>Inner span 11</span></span>
  <span>Div Span 3<span>Inner span 21<span>Inner span 22</span></span></span>
 </div>

The list would be like this
0 => Div span 1,
1 => Div span 2,
2 => Div span 11,
3 => Div span 3,
4 => Div span 21,
5 => Div span 22,

Comment: This example/question does not line up with the previous example and I consider a separate question. Also, these kinds of examples really should be part of the question. You can [edit] a question to supplement these details. Otherwise crucial bits of information are scattered across comments where they do not belong.

Comment: Thanks i will post new question now.

Answer (score 0):

There is [PR #702](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/pull/702) raised for the same. There are some ongoing discussion going on around that. 
As there is no any ETA/Conclusion on this yet. Meanwhile you can control all things from your identifier.

like if you want child element your identifier will be:- 
`In case of css:- <<parent identifier > child  >>`
`In case of xpath:- <<parent identifier/child>>`

There is limitation of using this approach is you cant have 2 different selector type as parent/child.